# Google Excel , formula

Tags: excel, google-sheets

Not that hard a question but somehow I cannot fix it.

I've got two tabs in a Google excel document.

One with formula on column `X1`

```
= if(V1>0, S1-V1, "")
```

and it's through out the `X:X` column

For Tab2 on Column `A1` it is

```
=if('Tab1 '!X1>0, 'Tab1 '!D1, "")
```

I am getting the values except for 0 in Tab2 `A1` even though some rows have nothing but the formula in the `X` column in Tab1.

that means the formula in tab1 `X1` is greater than 0 ?

Tab1

```
S   V   X
20  20  = if(V1>0,S1-V1,"")
```

Tab 2

```
A
=if('Tab1 '!X1>0,'Tab1 '!D1, "" )
```

Comment: There is no such thing as "Google Excel". Microsoft considers "Excel" to be its trademark; Google made a spreadsheet program that works a lot like Excel - but is in fact a different program. They call it "Google Docs Spreadsheet".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When performing comparisons, Google Sheets does indeed consider a zero-length text string ("") to be "greater than" zero, or any number for that matter. For what it's worth, MS Excel will do exactly the same.

In the most recent version of Google Sheets, you can get the formulae in Tab1 to return truly blank cells using

`=IF(V1>0,S1-V1,)`

This will make the formulae in Tab2 work as expected.

Then in Tab2, you might consider using the following single formula:

`=FILTER('Tab1 '!X:X,'Tab1 '!X:X>0)`

Comment: Thanks  :) didnt know about the "" is greater than 0 .

Answer (score 0):

A quick workaround would be to change the condition on the second tab from:

```
'Tab1 '!X1>0
```

to something that checks if the square is empty, and will deliberately give false if it is:

```
if('Tab1 '!X1="", 0, 'Tab1 '!X1="") > 0
```

So in the end, the full formula will be:

```
=if(if('Tab1 '!X1="", 0, 'Tab1 '!X1="") > 0,'Tab1 '!D1, "" )
```

Not exactly pretty, but it does the job.

Comment: It works for empty cells but returning values for X when its = 0 :(

Comment: You sure? In my implementation it works. Can you copy the code you have?

Comment: if(V1>0,S1-V1,"")  is some how is greater than "0" , so your formula was working fine if the cells are empty. but when s1 - v1 = 0 , its returning X1 value. 
its not that its wrong ,your formula helps :) compared to mine.